# Update values of a column in data.table based on another

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, key

I have 2 data tables. One data table looks like this:

```
DT1
     date         number  data1  data2 targetColumn
1:    2020-01-01     1       a      5       red
2:    2020-01-01     2       b      5      green
       ---
4500: 2020-08-31    874      t      4       red
```

And another one that looks like:

```
DT2
     date         number  datay  datax  fromColumn
1:    2020-08-01     1       a      5       red
2:    2020-08-01     2       b      5      green
       ---
500:  2020-08-31    874      t      4       red
```

I want to modify the `targetColumn` on `DT1` where the keys (`date` and `number`) match on both `DT1` and `DT2`. `DT1` is much larger (e.g. Historic data) and `DT2` consists of sample data.

I want to update the values on the `targetColumn` where the keys match based on the data of `fromColumn` on `DT2`. Keeping the data on the unmatched keys untouched.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Could you please `dput(head(DT1,20))` and `dput(head(DT2,20))` and paste the output in the question in order to help you!

Comment: ```DT1[DT2, targetColumn:= i.fromColumn, on = .(date, number)]```